# Don't display parent elements by default if their children satisfy a specified condition

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
<li class="container">
<div class="age">24</div>
<div class="married">no</div>
</li>

<li class="container">
<div class="age">27</div>
<div class="married">yes</div>
</li>

<li class="container">
<div class="age">34</div>
<div class="married">no</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Desired result**

That the `li` elements where the `div.married` contains `yes` do not show by default.
[This code](http://jsbin.com/urodit/168/edit) does that using Jquery.

But in my project there are a lot of entries, so **each time the page is loaded you can see the involved entries flickering away in a fraction of a second**. I presume this is because the page starts to gets displayed on your browser before fully loading the script that is loaded on the line just above the end of the body tag.

**Questions and remarks about a solution**

- Is there a way to do what I wanted using only css? (There is the
  `:contains` in css, but I don't want to rely on that because it is
  deprecated for css3)
- I tried making a seperate script entry in the `head` element for only that Jquery line but
  there is still a noticeable flickering.

Comment: Not possible with CSS, but you could hide all the entries on load, then show the appropriate ones. Instead of text flashing away, it will be blank then flash in

Comment: I take it you have no control server side on how the view is created? It seems odd, in my opinion, that you would want to hide so much data

Comment: @My Head Hurts: I have control over the server side, but I was thinking that the checkbox might be used quite a lot during one session of a user. If so, it would stress the server quite a lot if I implemented it server side.

Comment: @Bentley4 Where are you extracting the user data from? If it is from a database, you could change your query to only select users that are married. That shouldn't have much of an effect on the server.

Comment: @My head Hurts: Yes, its from a database. Would caching help if I implemented it server side? I have no experience with caching yet but I presume the answer is no. Btw, feel free to formulate your ideas in a seperate answer so I can accept it if satisfactory.

Comment: @Bentley4 I don't think that caching would help much in this case. Are you wanting to do anything with the non-married user data when it is on that web page? If not, I would just change your database query to extract only married users - that might even speed things up as there won't be as much data to process/draw in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid is not posible with pure CSS. I advice this aproach if you like to avoid the flicker effect:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
  ////Jquery in here/////  

  $(".married:contains(no)").parent().css('display','block');

   //////////////////////
 });
});
```

css:

```
li {
 display:none;
}
```